# How do I plot two moving points on the same line in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to develop an offline trajectory tracking web application for vehicles.... I am trying to make it so that the point representing the vehicles keeps moving as the vehicle location changes with information received from a gps sensor in the car while also changing the position of the phone or system doing the tracking..... I've tried JavaScript libraries like chart.js, canvas.js and Mapael.js

I would love suggestions on which libraries I can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have an Offline map API ( Leaflet is a good choice if you have not), you can use make a simple API that has the latest coordinates of the vehicle in the backend. In the front-end, you have few options. You can simply use polling using setInterval to get the latest coordinate in a certain interval and update the lat and lon of the object drawn on the map. Better and more optimised way of fetching data can be Websockets or SSE (Server-Sent Events).

Comment: I have tried leaflet and I believe it could work but I couldn't find a free offline map API